# My text won't flip on SVG Path, How can i do?

Tags: svg, text, flip

I've a little issue with my SVG Code..

When i created the SVG in Illustrator, everything was looking good as you can see in the picture below : https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1KHq.png

But when i've started to animate my SVG on my website, the result was different : The text flipped

Preview :

```html
<svg width="1770px" height="auto" viewBox="0 0 1770 1229.5">
    <path id="curve" fill="transparent" d="M1750,71.2v222c0,477.7-387.3,865-865,865h0c-477.7,0-865-387.3-865-865v-222H1750z"></path>
    <text width="100%" style="transform:translate3d(0,0,0);">
       <textPath
       startOffset=79.4751%
       opacity="100%"
       style="
       transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
       fill: #000000;
       fill-opacity: 0;
       stroke: #000000;
       stroke-width: 1px;
       stroke-linecap: butt;
       stroke-linejoin: miter;
       stroke-opacity: 1;" 
       
       xlink:href="#curve">Réserver un appel &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Réserver un appel &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Réserver un appel &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Réserver un appel
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Réserver un appel
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Réserver un appel
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Réserver un appel
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Réserver un appel
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Réserver un appel
       <animate
        attributeName="startOffset" from="0%" to="13%"
        dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        </textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```

Can anyone help me?

Thank's !

Comment: You may need to reverse the path. Pease try this d attribute: ` d="M20,293.2
             C20,770.9 407.3,1158.2 885,1158.2
             C1362.7,1158.2 1750,770.9 1750,293.2
             V71.2
             H20Z"` Also you may need to set a bigger font size.

Comment: @exaneta if only Chrome/Safari would implement side="right"